# ffmpeg convert one png to DNxHD

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to create a DNxHD file from one PNG file.  The output should be "24000/1001" fps, 1920x1080, using the dnxhd codec.  Every frame should be the same.  The outputted stream must be 20 seconds in length.

I have a solution which uses `filter_complex` to loop the PNG for each frame, however this results in extremely large files.  Given that I will be combining possibly multiple hundred DNxHD files into one AAF file, the output file size is too large.

Is there any improvement I can make on the command below which would achieve this file size reduction?

`ffmpeg -i INFILE.png -y -nostdin -an -vcodec dnxhd -pix_fmt yuv422p -vb 36M  -framerate 24000/1001 -filter_complex loop=479:1:0 OUFILE.dnxhd`

I do not know ffmpeg all that well, this command has been constructed by copying parts of commands I have found online.

Answer (score -1):

DNxHD is an intra-coded codec i.e. each frame is encoded (and thus decodable) independently of each other. So, the size can't be decreased without changing ratecontrol parameters like bitrate.

BTW, your command can be simplified to

`ffmpeg -framerate 24000/1001 -loop 1 -t 20 -i IN.png -c:v dnxhd -pix_fmt yuv422p -b:v 36M OUT.dnxhd`

framerate doesn't have any relevance when saving to a raw stream (`.dnxhd`); only when saving to containers like `.mov`. It is possible technically to construct a MOV file with only two frames, with the 2nd frame, having a timestamp 20 seconds forward, but not sure if your workflow will handle such files as desired.